# Exponential Integral in Julia

Tags: julia, exponential, integral

I am looking for an alternate function of `scipy.special.expi()` in julia. This function finds `exponential integral Ei`. More details can be found here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expi.html

Please suggest a solution to this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like https://github.com/JuliaMath/SpecialFunctions.jl has an implementation.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have found the answer from your suggested link. And i have posted an implementation for others to use it directly.
Highly appreciated !!!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Oscar, the equivalent alternative to `scipy.special.expi()` in julia can be implemented as follows:

```
using SpecialFunctions
#to find the exponential integral of x
expinti(x)
```